# Should a TA position which requires teaching a class offer more money than one that doesn't?

Tags: phd, united-states, teaching, salary, teaching-assistant

I am currently a PhD student (international) at a University in the US (TX). I was offered a TA position, however the position requires me to work as an instructor of the course. I worked before as well with a similar opportunity.

Being an instructor I have more work responsibilities compared to only being a TA. But for the instructor work I get paid the same as what I used to get for a TA.

Is this correct? If not, what should I do from my end as I feel this is unfair? I talked about this with my research advisor but he was not very helpful.

Comment: How exactly are you paid? In the models I know you have a TA position that is meant to take a certain amount of hours per week and comes with a fixed pay. Standing in front of a class as a TA counts for less hours that standing in front of class as an instructor and both cases count more hours than just the time standing in front of class because you also need to grade, hold office hours etc.

Comment: "I was offered a TA position, however the position requires me to work as an instructor of the course." Something's wrong here. By being an instructor (managing the course curriculum, dealing with the admins of setting up a course with the uni, coordinating the TAs) you're not being a TA by definition. If you meant that you got assigned some hours to lead a few sessions of the class, and there is still another dedicated instructor who manages the TAs, then you're not an instructor, you're a TA.

Comment: "should?" Is a subjective question. One argue that the more work you do, the now you should get paid. What does "more" here mean? Hard to say. Done can get done more in a shorter time and at a higher quality. Some work slower and output less quality. Just be sure to understand what is expected at minimum and what beyond the minimum is typical, and the pay, benefits, etc. Read your contract carefully and the relevant institutional policies.

Comment: What formal qualifications are needed to teach the class? Can any regular TA teach the class? Are similar classes usually taught by graduate lecturers or professors?

Comment: I made the syllabus, I instruct, recently got a grader assigned from the department after a long request and also maintain office hours. In total I manage everything except the departmental assignment. The model of payment is stipend based fixed for 20 hours.

Comment: It is not impossible the department has discretionary fund they could use, but typically if you're paid as a TA, you're a TA. Particularly because you're an international student, you may not be able to work as an instructor (as job which is not dependent on your student status) due to your student visa. But they may be able to secure a one time bonus amount; it's worth asking

Comment: I did this job as a graduate lecturer. This was after passing my Ph.D defense. In your position, I might want to talk to the ombudsman's office. Ask them if the everything is above board. Their office should be independent of any department and they can ask questions without ever revealing your identity.

Answer (score 13):

Every time you are offered a job, you should ask for more pay.  If you are unionized, read the contract first to see what you are allowed to ask for.  Otherwise, find out what the market rate is and ask for a bit more than that.

Since you specified this is the United States, I can say that [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/201230/13240)
has several inaccuracies.

First, in the United States, employees do not need a union to bargain collectively.  You can organize the other employees "waiting in line behind you" and request higher pay as a group.

Second, depending on your individual situation, it's not certain anyone else can do the job.

Third, while administration probably will say no to an increase in pay, they might say yes.  You would need to find the right person to ask.

I should also add:  Some universities claim, implausibly, that graduate students are not employees and are not protected by labor law.  There has been litigation about this in the past few years.  Public universities are governed by different laws from private universities.

I think it is unfair for instructors and TAs to be paid the same amount.  I think your university will agree.  Universities care about supply and demand.  They care about negotiating leverage.  But they also care about fairness and their reputation for fairness. I do not know if they will fix unfair pay, but asking for more pay is in your interest.  If you do not want the work, refuse it.

Comment: Is it still unfair if TAs are deliberately overpaid?

Comment: @fectin I consider that question to be unrelated to the reality we live in.  The highest PhD student pay I could quickly find in the US is $47,000.  Usually it is much less than that, with no floor.  In my opinion the floor should be about $60,000.

Comment: @Anonymus Physicist Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately no union exists and I reached out to the Dean. Waiting for their response.

Answer (score 7):

If graduate students at your institution have no union, you are out of luck. You can ask for more money, but as long as there's a line of people waiting behind you to teach for the same low pay, the university administration can just say no. Now, if all of you got together and refused to do extra work for no extra pay, the university would have to listen. That's what unions are for.

This is not to say that you should not ask. You should. A close friend of mine works at HR (pharma), and she tells me that they have employees side-by-side doing the same job making vastly different salaries. The difference is that one asked for more money, the other did not. So ask. What I am warning you is that over a long career in academia, I have never seen a graduate student successfully negotiate a higher salary, outside of a union context that is. I have even tried to negotiate on behalf of my students, and failed.

As in any negotiation, it boils down to leverage. The university has students to teach, and money in the bank. You have the ability to refuse to teach. If money is more scarce to you than TAs are to them, you lose. If you don't really need the money and they have a hard time finding TAs, you might be able to pry a salary increase from them. But don't count on it. At most universities, administrators will rather cancel a class than raise a salary.

On the merits of your argument, that being an instructor is more work than TAing, I'd say "it depends." When I was a grad student, I had to TA for a professor who pretty much abandoned the class to me, and that included lecturing, writing and grading exams, preparing labs from scratch, making and grading lab exams, etc. When I was an instructor for a lecture-only (ie no lab) course, the only work was to prep the lectures and grade the exams I wrote. So a lot less work. Since most institutions have non-negotiable TA rates (again, without unions), the battle among graduate students moves to who's teaching which class, as everybody wants the classes with a low workload.

Comment: As far as I know, our (unionized) graduate students get the same pay whether they teach a section of a course (as primary instructor) or just run recitation sections.

Comment: There are many things in this answer I disagree with, but I definitely agree unions are important.